# How to replace apps dock icon in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to replace my icon in apps dock when after installing my developed app. That means when I install my app (dialer), it shows on apps dock by replacing an existing one [image](stock dialer).

Answer (score 1):

There are many home screen implementations for Android. Not all of them have such a dock. There is no standard API for asking a home screen to replace something in a dock.

You are welcome to contact the developers of various home screens and see if they offer some API to allow you to replace an icon in their dock.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for several reasons.

First, the dock is basically a small drawer. The user can put an icon there themselves and the default one is specified by the launcher app.

Secondly, there is no common interface to ask the current launcher to add an icon to the dock. Many launchers do not have a dock at all! :-(

So, you should just let the user decide whether they want to have your app on the dock :-) Alternatively, you can write your own launcher which will put your app in the dock by default! :-D